# resharper how to replace all with implicitly typed local variables?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper

I know how to replace an explicit declaration with an implicit one using Resharper just in one click. But is it possible to do that by one click throughout the complete code file? Or is it possible for all files in solution?

Comment: Create your own `Code cleanup` profile ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this depends on Visual Studio version and Resharper version, but in Visual Studio 2013 and Resharper 8.1 this feature already exists. For example, I have a code

```
Random random = new Random();
```

The I hover over the declaration of type and I get a suggestion from Resharper `Use 'var'` and there are some additional options that can be accessed by pressing right arrow key on keyboard or by clicking on `>` with a mouse. The you get options:

- Use 'var' everywhere in file
- Use 'var' everywhere in folder
- Use 'var' everywhere in project
- Use 'var' everywhere in solution

You choose the desired option and Resharper does the rest.

Comment: FYI, This option doesn't exist in VS 2010 with ReSharper 8.2.0.2160. The only alternative is to create a custom code cleanup profile.